# Improve an edit by changing the tags is not possible

Tags: support, tags, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was reviewing [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14794668). The user added the language tag for proper formatting in VB.NET.

I would remove the C# tag and add the VB.NET one instead...

I wanted to improve edit, but there I cannot change the tags.

Should I:

- Approve the edit, then go to the question and change the tags myself?

The user was right to do this format change, but forgot the tag.

- Reject the edit, then change the tags?

If the tag is changed, maybe he doesn't even need to add the Visual Basic language tag before every chunk of code.

I'm trying to do my best on the review queue and many edits whenever I don't know the subject.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's an *answer* you're reviewing, not a question. The tags are only displayed as reference, but you (and the editor) can't change them of course; that would require an edit to the question.

What the editor calls tags are the `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` elements inserted in the post. Indeed, if the question was tagged with [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), they would not have been necessary. But, as @CodyGray notes, the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag is correct here, and the only way to get the right syntax highlighting for VB code is these kind of HTML comments.

Comment: OK thank you I didn't even notice it... I kinda feel stupid right now, but I guess it will pass...

Comment: *"Indeed, if the question was properly tagged, they would not have been necessary."* Incorrect. The question is tagged C#, but the answer includes code in VB.NET. No amount of tagging is going to fix that problem. Even if you argue that it's a generic .NET question and a C# language tag is inappropriate, a VB.NET language tag would be equally inappropriate. In this case, the only workable option is for each answer to indicate the correct formatting for the dialect they chose for their code samples. (Until such time as we get automatic language detection!)

Comment: @CodyGray thanks - I only looked at the answer, not the question itself.

Comment: Well, that's the same problem Martin had. :-)